# How to pass a HASH to the REST API using HTTP::Request::Common PUT request?

Tags: perl

I have a hash `$customs` which looks like:

```
{
   'custom1': 'a',
   'custom2': 'b',
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to pass it the a REST API. The data should look like:

```
{
    'data': {
        'customs': {
            'custom1': 'a',
            'custom2': 'b',
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The code:

```
my @data = [{ 'customs' => \%customs }];
my $request = PUT($url,@data);
```

But in my REST API I see that the `data` is:

```
{'customs': ['HASH(0x1e47648)']}
```

How should I pass it right?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP::Request::Common is a low-level HTTP library. [`PUT`'s arguments are keys and values for a form request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common#POST-$url,-Header-=%3E-Value,...,-Content-=%3E-$content). Instead, you want to send some arbitrary data as JSON.

`PUT` will not do this for you. You need to do the [JSON encoding](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#encode_json), pass that as the content of the request, and set the content type.

```
require JSON;

my $data = { data => { customs => \%customs } };

my $request = PUT(
  $url,
  Content_Type => 'application/json'
  Content => JSON->new->utf8->encode($data)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider something a bit more friendly, such as Mojo::UserAgent. It handles many of the details for you:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $data = { data => { customs => \%customs } };

my $tx = $ua->post( $url, json => $data )
```

I have [another example in a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59962381/2766176).